# CentOS 7 within VirtualBox - localforward not working for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, networking, virtualbox, centos7

PostgreSQL runs on a cloud CentOS server (pg.mydomain.com). In my VirtualBox Windows guest (configured with one network adapter with NAT) I run putty with tunnelling option `L15432 127.0.0.1:5432` for pg.mydomain.com. E.g. with pgadmin3 I can access the remote PostgreSQL server very well.

Similar configuration with VirtualBox CentOS guest doesn't work. Same single vbox network interface (with NAT), within `~/.ssh/config` I have `localforward 15432 pg.mydomain.com:5432`. After starting a ssh terminal session I can access any web site on pg.mydomain.com (also forwarded in `~/.ssh/config`), but I cannot access PostgreSQL (e.g. with pgadmin4). pgadmin4 error is "*Server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.*".

I tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 25432`, works in Windows guest, but not in CentOS guest (error: *Connection closed by foreign host*).

EDIT: It seems to me there is a connection, but this connection is cancelled immediately after connecting.

What config detail could be different between Windows and CentOS guest?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: In ~/.ssh/config I wrote:

```
Host myhost
    hostname www.myhost.com
    localforward 15432 www.myhost.com:5432
```

This is wrong. The correct entry is:

```
Host myhost
    hostname www.myhost.com
    localforward 15432 127.0.0.1:5432
```